# JPA - Spring boot -@OneToMany persistence works fine but i get a strange object when returning Json object

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence, spring-boot, one-to-many

I have two entities `( Category | product )` with `@OneToMany` bidirectional relationship.

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    public Category() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Category(String name,String description) {
        this.name=name;
        this.description=description;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long cid;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Product> products;
    /..getters and setter.../

    }

    @Entity
    public class Product {
    public Product() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Product(long price, String description, String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.name=name;
        this.description=description;
        this.price=price;

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long pid;

    private long price;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @ManyToOne  
    private Category category;
    /..getters and setters../
    }
```

in my controller I have a function /categoris that add a new category with one product,    it works great and in my database I've got a foreign category id

But when i try to retrieve all the categories with responseBody i got a strange object exactely in category ( i want have in product, category : the category id instead of the object it's self )

```
public @ResponseBody Category create() {
    Category c=new Category("LIGA","messi feghouli cristiano");

    Product p=new Product(200,"jahd besaf","Real Madrid");

    if(c.getProducts()!=null){
        c.addProducts(p);
    }else{
        Set<Product> products=new HashSet<Product>();           
        products.add(p);
        c.setProducts(products);
    }
    p.setCategory(c);

    cDao.save(c);  pDao.save(p);        
    return c;
}


@RequestMapping(value="/categories",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Category> categories() {
    return cDao.findAll();
}
```

this is the strage object that i got :

```
{"cid":1,"name":"LIGA","description":"messi feghouli cristiano","products":[{"price":200,"name":"Real Madrid","description":"jahd besaf","category":{"cid":1,"name":"LIGA","description":"messi feghouli cristiano","products":[{"price":200,"name":"Real Madrid","description":"jahd besaf","category":{"cid":1,"name":"LIGA","description":"messi feghouli cristiano","products":[{"price":200,"name":"Real Madrid","description":"jahd besaf","category":{"cid":1,"name":"LIGA","description":"messi feghouli cristiano","products":
```

Comment: And why is it strange? What do you expect?

Comment: I expect to have just the Id of the category instead of all the object like this :
{ "cid":1,
 "name":"LIGA",
 "description":"messi feghouli cristiano",
 "products":[{
        "price":200,
        "name":"Real Madrid",
        "description":"jahd besaf",
        "category":1
                 }] 
}

Comment: No, you get the whole object hierachie.

Comment: yes I know but is it correct what i having

Comment: even if it's infinite ? because when retrieving it I have and error in spring boot telling me :getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly as it should be.

If you wish to avoid a circular reference, use the `@JsonBackReference` annotation. This prevents Jackson (assuming you're using Jackson) from going into an infinite loop and blowing your stack.

If you want the ID instead of the entity details, then create `getProductID` & `getCategoryID` methods and annotate the entity accessor with `@JsonIgnore`.